# Append Access query into SQL Server table using VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, append, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run VBA code that will append data from a MS Access table to a SQL Server table. I know there is an importer but this is what they asked for. I have tried but can't seem to figure out how to get this to work and I am not real knowledgeable on VBA and have looked on the internet and cant find any answers so here I am.

When I run code below I keep getting syntax error insert into statement.

Code:

```
Sub site()

    Dim newsql As String
    Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    newsql = "insert into dbo.SQLTABLE ( col1 ) " & _
             "in 'odbc;Driver={odbc driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;'" & _
             "select distinct col1 from access_table"

    db.Execute newsql

End Sub
```

Comment: The usual approach is to **link** the ODBC table from Access (using the connect string you already have), and then run the INSERT into the linked table. -- See 2nd example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase

Answer (score 1):

I've checked mutiple references, there is no direct query between Access local table and SQL Server table.

I worked out for ODBC 17 for SQL Server like this:

```
Sub site65655707()
    Dim ndone

    Dim newsql As String
    Dim db As Database
'
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

    Set db = CurrentDb

'
'   newsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.SQLTABLE ( col1 ) " & _
'     "in 'odbc;Driver={odbc driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;'" & _
'     "SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM access_table"
'
'
'   create a remote connection using ConnectionString:
'
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
'
    cnn.Open "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

'
'  open source DAO.Recordset from local Access table:
'
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM access_table;")
'
'   loop over all source data, and insert into SQL Server table 1 by 1:
'
    While (Not rst.EOF)
      '
      newsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.SQLTABLE ( col1 ) VALUES ('" & rst!col1 & "');"
      cnn.Execute newsql, ndone
      '
      rst.MoveNext
      '
    Wend
'
    rst.Close
'
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
'
    Set db = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

This required that Microsoft ADODB Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library beeing installed. As though DAO objects are installed by default in Microsoft Access.

[image]